# How to write NSLog into a file

Tags: objective-c, logging, freopen

I want to know that how to write NSLog into a file with some kind of constraint such as file size.

Actually, I already know to redirect a stdout(stderr) to a specific file.
That is, using `freopen(filePath, "a+", stderr);`

Using the above thing, I can save a debug logs into a file, but file size could be larger.

I want to make a log file that size is under the 5MB(or a specific file size).

To do this, What should I do ?

Comment: Do you have access to the logging application's source code? Or do you want to redirect and limit log messages from all apps? What about compiled code in your project (frameworks)?

Comment: I have an access to my application's source code. actually, I developed my own framework(and library), and the user used it.

Comment: Did you check for ASL (Apple System Logging)?